# Error with `apt upgrade` help

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

There's an error when I do
`sudo apt upgrade`

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpulsedsp : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.6) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.7 is installed
 pulseaudio : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.6) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.7 is installed
 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.6) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.7 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After typing in `sudo apt --fix-broken install` it gives this error:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpulsedsp pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
Suggested packages:
  pavumeter pavucontrol paman paprefs ubuntu-sounds
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpulsedsp pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/896 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,192 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency p
roblems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: too many err
ors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I checked on `df -ih` to see if boot is full but it wasn't

Output:

```
df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             476K   572  476K    1% /dev
tmpfs            487K  1.1K  486K    1% /run
/dev/sda1         15M  511K   14M    4% /
tmpfs            487K    42  487K    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            487K     3  487K    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            487K    18  487K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0        13K   13K     0  100% /snap/core/9993
/dev/loop1       4.1K  4.1K     0  100% /snap/pycharm-community/211
tmpfs            487K    72  487K    1% /run/user/120
tmpfs            487K    89  487K    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdc1        125K    20  125K    1% /media/papp/34c06214-5cb6-42b6-b033-9c53b228a584
/dev/sdc2        881M   26K  881M    1% /media/papp/Merevlemez
```

So does this mean the task manager got corrupted or something?
System: POP!_OS 20.04

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same problem too, in Pop OS 20.04

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

solved the issue for me.

See [Strange error when updating in the terminal](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506221931/https://pop-planet.info/forums/threads/strange-error-when-updating-in-the-terminal.1047/).

Comment: The linked post is about problems with a different package. If you really have exactly the same problem and this generic solution solved it for you, the question should probably be marked as a duplicate of an existing question where this is not only solved, but also explained.

Comment: This worked for me, almost, I had to run this: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, followed by: `sudo apt --fix-broken install`.

Comment: I had the same problem on Pop OS, and this solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks you so much! :)