# dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I got the following message after running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`, I also have been unable to update my packages from the store.

```
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on libpcre3; however:
  Package libpcre3:i386 is not configured yet.
```

Comment: We don't know your OS & release details, nor if you followed the suggestions in your messages to fix the problem (you only provided part of the messages for your unstated release, read it all and it'll suggest the solution; did you try what it suggested?)

Comment: tbh I have no idea what I'm supposed to do, I'm using Pop_OS!

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: To be fair, Pop is System76's official Ubuntu flavor. XD

Answer (score 97, accepted):

[Error with `apt upgrade` help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280769/error-with-apt-upgrade-help)

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

followed by:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Simple and easy answer... too much time spent weeding through the fodder, above,. Thanks @usernumber!

Comment: The `sudo apt --fix-broken install` actually gets recommended by the system if you try running `sudo apt update`: `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`. It would be useful if the system also recommended the above `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: Can someone explain why this works and what it is doing?